# 3,840 cronjobs with no action!

Tags: debug, cron, timezones

I have a site which constantly has nearly 4,000 cronjobs with no action. If I delete a number of these jobs they come right back, generally to the same number.

I've tried switching back to the Twenty Twenty-Two theme, disabling all the plugins (except for WP Control or WP Cron Cleaner, so I can see the events) and I still have all these. If I delete some they all come back.

[image: List of cron jobs]

Does anyone have any idea where else I might look to find the cause?

I also have many errors coming from the timezone setting, I'm not sure if this is related.

If I var_dump( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) ); I get "float(-7)" - the site is in the Pacific timezone, so what I expect.

[image: PHP error log]

Comment: this is possibly because cron jobs are encountering fatal errors, but there's no way to answer this with the information provided, there's nowhere near enough information. You'll need to edit this to be a specific question as right now it's an open ended investigation and that doesn't fit into the format of this site

Comment: Also those warnings are not talking about `$gmtOffset`, they're referring to `$timestamp`. Whatever is responsible for registering those cron jobs is where you should look, clearly they're not being registered properly